Commutative diagram, better than with matrix
Could someone provide a decent way of drawing the following picture?
$$
\begin{matrix*}
&\mathbb H&\overset{T}{\longrightarrow}&\mathbb H&
\\
\text{\footnotesize P}&\downarrow&&\uparrow& J
\\
&(\ker T)^{\perp}&\overset{\tilde T}{\longrightarrow}&\range T&
\\
&\val{\tilde T}\searrow&&\nearrow W&
\\
&&(\ker T)^{\perp}&&
\end{matrix*}
$$


First of never use $$...$$ in LaTeX, next have a look at the tikz-cd package.

Could you please add an image (also drawn by hand) of what should be the desired result?

Addiotnally please extend your code into something that can be compiles. Fx where does \range and \val  come from?

For commutative diagrams people usually use tikz-cd package.


your question is very unclear
code fragment with unknown commands is not helpful at all
for commutative diagrams exist dedicated packages like tikz-cd etc.
an example (by accidental may be close to what you after) which may serve as starting point for your commutative diagram can be:

\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\mathbb{H}  \ar[r, "T"]     
            \ar[d, "P"]     &   \mathbb{H}      \\
\ker{T}^{\perp} \ar[r, "\tilde{T}"] 
                \ar[ur, "W" sloped]      
                            &   \ker{T}^{\perp} \ar[u, "P"]    
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}



Thx for your help. The picture provided by egreg is fine with me.

@Bazin, it will be far better if you make your question more clear. (that we not need to guess). Since you not do this, -1 for it ...

I guess you mean something like
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\DeclareMathOperator{\range}{range}
\newcommand{\val}[1]{#1}% ???

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large,column sep=small]
\mathbb{H} \ar[rr,"T"] \ar[d,"P"'] && \mathbb{H}
\\
(\ker T)^{\perp} \ar[dr,"\val{\tilde{T}}"'] \ar[rr,"\tilde{T}"] && \range T \ar[u,"J"']
\\
&(\ker T)^{\perp} \ar[ur,"W"']
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}

Peruse the manual of tikz-cd. I made a guess about \range, but I couldn't do for \val.
Train yourself into never using $$ and to use braces around arguments, such as \mathbb{H}.


I have copied from output of @Zarko.

Great, thank you very much!

I'm curious to see that you put the diagram inside \[...\]. Is there a reason for that?

@AndrewStacey It's usual for commutative diagrams to be displayed.

Curious. I think I tended to put them in figures, but it's been so long since I used a commutative diagram in anger ...

@AndrewStacey They're staple food for people working with modules and rings or, more generally, with categories.

Oh, I'm well aware what they are! It's just that I've not written a paper for so long (not being in academia any more), that I haven't had to think about how I would typeset one in an article.

Just looked back at a paper where I made extensive use of them (to the extent of having a commutative diagram style) and I put them all in a centre environment, not in \[...\].  (For the pedantic, I do have \let\centre\center and \let\endcentre\endcenter in my preamble)

(And to be very clear, I fully realise that there are going to be different ways of achieving essentially the same end, and that there is not One True Way to include a commutative diagram in an article. I was just a little surprised to see you use \[...\] - since we often see that mis-used to centre something that isn't maths - and so assumed you had thought deeply about it and was just curious as to why.)

A quick version with xy package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\xyoption{rotate}
\xyoption{pdf}

\begin{document}
\[\xymatrix@R=2pc@C=3pc{
\mathbb{H}  \ar[r]^T \ar[d]^P &  \mathbb{H}      \\
\ker{T}^{\perp} \ar[r]^{\tilde{T}} 
 \ar[ur]^[@!+30]{W} & \ker{T}^{\perp} \ar[u]^P   
}
\]
\end{document}


Seeing the output of @egreg I add the version with xy package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rg}{range}
\begin{document}
\xymatrix@R=3pc@C=1.5pc{\mathbb{H} \ar[rr]^T \ar[d]_P && \mathbb{H}
\\
(\ker T)^{\perp} \ar[dr]_{\tilde{T}} \ar[rr]^{\tilde{T}} && \rg T \ar[u]_J
\\
&(\ker T)^{\perp} \ar[ur]_W
}
\end{document}


